# Does the human spirit rise up after a person dies?

Tags: acts, isaiah, ecclesiastes, death, spirits

New International Version
Ecclesiastes 12:

> 7
> before the dust returns to the ground from which it came and the **spirit returns to God** who gave it.

This is confirmed in
Act 7:

> 54 When the members of the Sanhedrin heard this, they were furious and gnashed their teeth at him. 55But Stephen, full of the Holy Spirit, looked **up to heaven** and saw the glory of God, and Jesus standing at the right hand of God. 56“Look,” he said, “I see heaven open and the Son of Man standing at the right hand of God.” ...
>
> 59 While they were stoning him, Stephen prayed, “Lord **Jesus, receive my spirit**.” 60Then he fell on his knees and cried out, “Lord, do not hold this sin against them.” When he had said this, he fell asleep.

On the other hand,
Isaiah 26:

> 14
> They are now dead, they live no more; their **spirits do not rise**. You punished them and brought them to ruin; you wiped out all memory of them.

This is my question,
Ecclesiastes 3:

> 21
> Who knows if the human spirit rises upward and if the spirit of the animal goes down into the earth?”

Comment: The translation you are using for Isaiah does not accurately reflect the Hebrew. Your highlighted segment comes from ‘rᵊp̄ā'îm’ - which simply doesn’t mean what your translation says.

Comment: Which version would you recommend?

Comment: I don’t advocate any particular translation.  I was commenting that the one you use *here* is inaccurate. Essentially Isaiah 26:14 is talking about the spirits of the (dead) raphaim - not *human* (man’s) spirit. This is clear from the Hebrew.

Comment: In this case, which translation would you recommend from https://biblehub.com/parallel/isaiah/26-14.htm ?

Comment: That link leads to a very interesting resource, it makes translation differences *very* clear  - thanks! I would recommend those that indicate this verse is *not* talking about ‘human’ spirits, and there certainly are a few. For example, Young’s literal.

Comment: Great. Expand it into an answer and I'll upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

According to King James we have in *Galatians 5:22* the following:

> 22 But the fruit of the Spirit is love, joy, peace, longsuffering,
> gentleness, goodness, faith.

Then, it's not hard to verify that the word *spirit* in this context is different from that you have pointed out, which is *Isaiah 26:14*; in this case *spirit* simply means the **soul**, which in this case isn't saved, the **soul** of the lords that are not *The Lord* as it says in the verse 13 of the same chapter:

> 13 O Lord our God, other lords beside thee have had dominion over us:
> but by thee only will we make mention of thy name.

As it's written in *2 Corinthians 3:18*, G'd is the Spirit, then the Spirit never dies, since He is Life, the Eternal:

> 18 But we all, with open face beholding as in a glass the glory of the
> Lord, are changed into the same image from glory to glory, even as by
> the Spirit of the Lord.

Another view of this can be found, *spirit* meaning **soul**:

> 80 And the child grew, and waxed strong in spirit, and was in the
> deserts till the day of his shewing unto Israel.

*obs.: a good observation is to perceive if spirit is written with capital letters or not, even though there's a possibility of a mistake along the translation*

Comment: You say "the Spirit never dies" and "spirit meaning soul" but Ezekiel 18:4 says "the soul that sinneth, it shall die". How can that be?

Comment: Yes, exactly, the soul that sinns shall die, but the Spirit which isn't the soul, never dies. Ezekiel is correct then.

Comment: @João Víctor Melo  Hi Victor, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Comment: I'd be wary of using capitals to decide what a word refers to - at best it tells you what the translator thought it meant. This is where sound exegesis can be really helpful